# Retrieve the XML "id" attribute value when given an element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, methods

Thank you for reading this.  I need to get the names of the `<table>` elements in an XML document and use those names to poulate a combo box on a winform.  I am trying to create a method in c# to retrieve the value of an 'id' attribute based on the xml structure:

```
<root>
     <object>
          <objects>
               <table id="tableName">
               </table>
          </objects>
     </object>
</root>
```

I have looked on the Microsoft docs site and have found several things talking about getelementbytagname or getelementbyid.  Those are close but they are not getting me the information I need.  I also tried pathing to them in a method using xpath in order to retrieve the data but I cannot get it to work.  This is probably super elementary but I have searched online for two days now and can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could Parse (or Load, in case it is an .xml file) it using Linq To XML and get what you want. With this very few data there is no identification but this would get you started:

```
void Main()
{
    string myXML = @"<root>
     <object>
          <objects>
               <table id=""tableName"">
               </table>
          </objects>
     </object>
</root>";

    var ids = XElement.Parse(myXML).DescendantsAndSelf("table")
              .Where(xe => xe.Attribute("id") != null)
              .Select(xe => (string)xe.Attribute("id"));
              
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```